# Asynchronous Background task in python with asyncio library

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm looking to run a heavy computing task in the background without blocking IO. Problem here is my main function does not depend on the heavy task and needs to return value before/while executing the heavy computing task. As an example:

```
def main(args):
   transformed_data_list:List[Dict] = translate_request_to_object(args)
   status = insert_data_into_db(transformed_data:Dict)
   if(status)
      # running background task
      asyncio.run(process_background_task(transformed_data_list))

   # Here, I want to return a success response as soon as data inserted into db
   return "data insert into db"
```

```
   async process_background_task(transformed_data_list:List[Dict]):
      for data in transformed_data_list:List:
         asyncio.create_task(heavy_computation_task(data))
```

But above code not returning response until `process_background_task` completed.

Answer (score 5):

## How to run task in background

[`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) is the blocking function that starts event loop. If you want to start `process_background_task` in background you need to use [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) and make `main` asynchronous. Then run `asyncio.run(main(...))`.

```
async def main(args):
    transformed_data_list:List[Dict] = translate_request_to_object(args)
    status = insert_data_into_db(transformed_data:Dict)
    if status:
        # running background task
        asyncio.create_task(process_background_task(transformed_data_list))

    # Here, I want to return a success response as soon as data inserted into db
    return "data insert into db"


async process_background_task(transformed_data_list:List[Dict]):
    for data in transformed_data_list:List:
        asyncio.create_task(heavy_computation_task(data))

# Start event loop, execute task and wait until task finish.
asyncio.run(main(...))
```

## How to run heavy tasks in event loop

But in the case `heavy_computation_task` will block event loop you need to use [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) with [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

Here is the example from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor):

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

def cpu_bound():
    # CPU-bound operations will block the event loop:
    # in general it is preferable to run them in a
    # process pool.
    return sum(i * i for i in range(10 ** 7))

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    # Run in a custom process pool:
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, cpu_bound)
        print('custom process pool', result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

In your case:

```
async def main(args):
    transformed_data_list:List[Dict] = translate_request_to_object(args)
    status = insert_data_into_db(transformed_data:Dict)
    if status:
        # running background task
        asyncio.create_task(process_background_task(transformed_data_list))

    # Here, I want to return a success response as soon as data inserted into db
    return "data insert into db"


async process_background_task(transformed_data_list:List[Dict]):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    for data in transformed_data_list:List:
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
            await loop.run_in_executor(pool, heavy_computation_task, data)

# Start event loop, execute task and wait until task finish.
asyncio.run(main(...))
```

Comment: Could you please why you suggest `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor `? And from where I call  `asyncio.run(main(...))` will again block that parent function, right?

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor` can run simultaneously only one task, so it only suits IO-bound operations, but not CPU-bound operations. `ProcessPoolExecutor` can run many tasks simultaneously.

Comment: `asyncio.run(main(...))` will block the function where it runs.