# Background task with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have one class `produceMessages` that keeps feeding messages to its attribute `message_logs`.
I want to process these messages in the other class `processMessages`. However, the code in `processMessages` won't execute until `produceMessages` is done - which is never, as I want these messages to come forever.

Looking at documentation, I've found that the library asyncio might help me but I'm struggling to get the below example work:

This is first_file.py:

```
import asyncio
import random

class produceMessages:
    def __init__(self, timeout = 10):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.message_logs = []

    async def run(self):
        while(True):
            self.message_logs.append(random.uniform(0, 1))           
            await asyncio.sleep(self.timeout)
```

This is second_file.py:

```
import first_file
import asyncio
import time

class processMessages:
    def __init__(self):
        self.producer = first_file.produceMessages()
        asyncio.run(self.producer.run())

    def print_logs(self):
        print(self.producer.message_logs)
        time.sleep(1)

x = processMessages()
x.print_logs()
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous Background task in python with asyncio library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563787/asynchronous-background-task-in-python-with-asyncio-library)